# No IMvxImageHelper registered

Tags: android, imageview, mvvmcross, imageurl

I use mvvmcross and can not bind to image URL. Error: No IMvxImageHelper registered - you must provide an image helper before you can use a MvxImageView

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
        p1:id="@+id/imgArticle"
        p1:layout_width="49dp"
        p1:layout_height="49dp"
        p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        p1:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Image, Converter = Image"
        p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        p1:background="#ffff0000" />
```

My Model:

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: Make sure you install the DownloadCache plugin. This provides the proper helper implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the DownloadCache plugin and MVVMCross File plugin

Comment: On the portable and the droid projects?

Comment: On dorid projects :) @DaneMackier

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue in android. What I did to fix it was adding the bootstrap classes.

```
 public class DownloadCachePluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.PluginLoader>
    {
    }

public class FilePluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.File.PluginLoader>
    {
    }
```